# Add Expression to Value of Array in Twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I can't wrap my head around this. I'm on mobile so forgive me. I'm trying to add dynamic values to an array like this:

```
{%  set myArray = myArray|merge("href": {{ product.href }})%}.
```

I'm getting the 'A hash key must be a quotes string, a number, a name...'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error .

It is wrong

```
{%  set myArray = myArray|merge("href": {{ product.href }})%}.
```

Use this code instead

```
   {%  set myArray = myArray|merge({ 'href': product.href } ) %}.
```

The merge filter works on hashes.
For hashes, the merging process occurs on the keys: if the key does not already exist, it is added but if the key already exists, its value is overridden.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's better to explain what needs to be changed than just dropping a line of code without further explanation.